# Doubt in Functional Testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Below is my functional test code

def test_should_create_county

```
assert_difference('County.count') do
  post :create, :county => {:name=>"myname",:description=>"mydesc",:region_id=>"3" }
end
assert_redirected_to county_path(assigns(:county))
```

end

end

And error message i got is

29) Failure:
test_should_create_county(CountiesControllerTest) [/test/functional/counties_controller_test.rb:16]:
"County.count" didn't change by 1.
<3> expected but was
<2>.

Please help

-- 
Karthik.k
Mobile - +91-9894991640

Comment: you should read about how to use StackOverflow code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Country object is not being created in the `create` action. There's not enough presented to determine the reason, but here are a few common cases (in order of most common).

- validation is failing on Country model
- authentication or authorization is being triggered
- some other redirection through a before filter (for https or domain name change)

Take a look at your validations on the Country model, does the :country option given in the test make a valid model? If not I recommend [using factories](http://railscasts.com/episodes/158-factories-not-fixtures) to generate valid model attributes.

If validation isn't the problem, take a look at the controller before filters to ensure a redirect isn't happening there.

You may want to move the `assert_redirect` into the `assert_difference` block which could give a more descriptive error.